# Что необходимо выполнить чтобы освободить память, которую занимает объект object?

Tags: java

Или нет возможности проконтролировать освобождение памяти ?

Comment: можете вручную запустить сборщик мусора разве что. Но не факт, конечно, что он очистит память вашего объекта при этом вызове.

Comment: если ответ помог, можно поставить галочку чтобы принять его как верный

Comment: К сожалению не увидел где это можно сделать.

Comment: @Идентикон слева от ответа, под галочками стрелочками рейтинга есть галочка. Но это конечно же на Ваше усмотрение.

Answer (score 1):

Сослать указатель объекта на другой объект, либо на `null`. Старый объект останется без ссылки на него и будет подлежать удалению из памяти. После либо дождаться пока GC соберет мусор сам, либо подсказать приложению запустить его с помощью команды `System.gc()`. Однако это тоже не гарантирует немедленный запуск GC.

Comment: Однако `System.gc` вообще не означает, что сборщик сиюминутно начнет свою работу. JVM решает когда это сделать. Более того, этот вызов заставляет проседать приложение в производительности

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я конечно не уверен в том, что он всегда запускается сразу же при принудительном указании, но в моих случаях это всегда помогало освободить память. И было отчетливо видно в VisualVM как он запускался.

Comment: Думаю это какое-нибудь счастливое везение. Не более того.

Comment: Даже ребята с enSO  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632734/can-we-call-the-garbage-collector-explicitly  об этом пишут `When you make call using System.gc(), it is just a request to JVM and JVM can anytime decide to ignore it.` и пр.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский поправил ответ. Спасибо за инфу